# Exporting data to excel mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, export-to-excel, windows-mobile-6

Is there ability to export data from my .netcf application to excel mobile by running excel application as com object and filling sheet using excel object model?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Pocket Excel/Excel Mobile has no object model or automation interface.  Your best bet is to export data as a CSV, which you can then open in Excel.